# Django: posting a template value to a view

Tags: python, html, django

### The Problem:

I'm tying to post to a view and pass on a value from the template by using a hidden value field and a submit button. The values from the submit button (ie the csrf_token) gets through but the hidden value does not. I've checked from the Wezkrug debugger that `request.POST` only contains form values and not my `'id'` value from the hidden field.

#### Background:

The button takes you to a form where you can enter a comment. I'm trying to include the `review.id` that the user is commenting on to make commenting easy. I have the value as 'test' not for test purposes.

My form:

```
<div>
     <form method='POST' action='/add_comment/'>
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="hidden" name='id' value='test'>
         <input type="submit" value="Make a Comment">
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment View:

```
@login_required
def make_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            # render?
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/', {
                'restaurant': get_object_or_404(
                                                Restaurant, 
                                                name=request.POST['name'], 
                                                address=request.POST['address']
                                                )
                })
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'stamped/comment.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment ModelForm Code:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ('user', 'review',)
```

I've been trying to follow the tactics in this question, but using the request.session dict is undesirable because Id have to store an id for every review regardless if they're are ever commented on.

[What is a more efficient way to pass variables from Template to View in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097475/what-is-a-more-efficient-way-to-pass-variables-from-template-to-view-in-django)

Any ideas on how to include the hidden value in the POST? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your view code for the `add_comment` action?

Comment: @Brandon, I've updated my question with the comment view

Comment: I don't see where you're referencing `request.POST.get('id')` anywhere in your view code.

Comment: I'm using the Werkzeug interactive to inspect `request.POST`. Executing `request.POST.get('id')` returns nothing, `request.POST` shows me the queryset which doesnt contain the `id` value as well (im not sure that its supposed to, I just thought it would be a place to check)

Comment: What does: `print request.POST` tell you from your Django view?

Comment: `<QueryDict: {u'content': [u'kkkkk'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'M96J3MrtMNvlaXN207faicFwpS9VkOb6']}>`

Comment: Where does `content` come from? That's not represented in the HTML in your question. Please be as accurate as possible in representing the form so others can tell what's going on.

Comment: The content comes from the ModelForm (I've added the model above). Also the view is executing once when the page loads with out prompting as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36212/discussion-between-brandon-and-agconti)

Comment: are you sure commentform is valid? can we see its code? plus, I suggest you use `request.POSt.get()` also for restaurant and address, to prevent failures

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo The code for the model is just an automatically generated model form (I've included it above). Also what advantages does `request.POSt.get()` over dictionary access to prevent failures?

Comment: dict access gives you a `KeyError` while with get you can provide a default value (or let it use the default None) without breaking your app (if not handled, a keyerror will make your user experience a nice 500). Plus in your html I don't see `{{ form }}`, just the hidden field.

Comment: I'm not trying to implement the `CommentForm` here. The listed html just shows a form that contains a 'comment' button that takes you to the `CommentForm`. I'm trying to pass a template value to that `CommentForm` from this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

views.py

```
def make_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'prepair_comment' in request.POST:
            review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=request.POST.get('id'))
            form = CommentForm({'review': review.id})
            return render(request, 'stamped/comment.html', {
                'form': form,
                })
        else: # save the comment
```

models.py

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
               model = Comment
               exclude = ('user',)
               widgets = {'review': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

restaurant.html

```
<form method='POST' action='/add_comment/'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' value='{{ r.id }}' name='id'>
    <input type="submit" name='prepair_comment' value="Make a Comment">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Goldhand, thanks for your answer. You can see in my question above that I've been checking `request.POST` for my 'id' field and found that it only contains form values and not my 'id' value from the hidden field. This is the crux of the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. This is a great solution but the `r.id` is still not contained in the `request.POST` `QueryDict`, which is still where this process is de-railing. That's the obstacle I'm trying to overcome.  Did you try this code? If so, then I know its something unique to my setup.

Comment: Ya I got the review_id through, but wasn't sure where to find the name and address vars. Here's the error (you can see the review var there too) `"Key 'name' not found in <QueryDict: {u'content': [u'sdf'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'ZqMNTAqahh739ZvUvDLOIn4mwilbDNpd'], u'review': [u'1']}>"`

Comment: Ahh thats exactly what I'm trying to accomplish! I'm just not sure whats getting in the way.

Comment: Is this necessary for the querydict to contain the hidden value? `widgets = {'review': forms.HiddenInput()}`

Comment: I think its because you're posting twice; when you click 'create comment' on restaurant.html it submits to 'make_comment' and you lose the review id. The 'make_comment' view renders again with errors but without the review_id. I removed the exclude field in the commentform just in case.

Comment: Any idea on how to stop posting twice?

Comment: The querydict actually does need the hidden value: `widgets = {'review': forms.HiddenInput()}` and it will still work if you post twice as long as you pass the review_id from the first to the second post. You could do `make_comment(request, pk)` and use the review_id for the pk

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form with `form.cleaned_data`.  You could also use a `if form.is_valid()` or if you want to ignore the hidden test value when there is no comment, then you could use a if/else logic to ignore the hidden value `if comment is None:` logic.

To access the form and only record the test value if comment is not None, the `views.py` might look like this:

```
 def form_view(request):
      if request.method == 'POST'
        form = form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
          # do something with other fields
          if comment is not None:
            id = form.cleaned_data['test']
            # do something with the hidden 'id' test value from the form
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
       else:
         form = form()
       return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here are the Django Docs that I would reference for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: I think you might be confused on my question.  I don't have a problem with adding comments to the database, displaying them, or dealing with  the functionality of the form itself. I'm looking to pass a template value through post method to a view. Here it just a happens to be that that view contains a `ModelForm`.