# How to save queryset in models from template data by logged in user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    match_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter the name of 2 team using vs (eg. ban vs ind)')
    first_team = models.ForeignKey('FirstTeam', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    second_team = models.ForeignKey('SecondTeam', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tournament_name = models.ForeignKey('TournamentName', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    match_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    match_stated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

In views:

```
def league(request, pk):
    match = Match.objects.all()

    context = {
        'match': match,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/league.html', context=context)
```

In templates:

```
{% for match in match %}
  <div class="row text-center py-2">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="{{ match.first_team.flag.url }}" alt="image" class="team-image">
      <h6>{{ match.first_team.name }}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <p>{{ match.tournament_name }}</p>
      <div>Starts On: <div style="color: red;">{{ match.match_stated|date:"d F, Y. h:i A" }}</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="{{ match.second_team.flag.url }}" alt="image" class="team-image">
      <h6>{{ match.second_team.name }}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">join</button>
{% endfor %}
```

In my admin site, I add many data for my models without `user` fields and i show that queryset in my `templates`. This is working properly.

Now, i need to save queryset for logged-in `user` from the `templates`. In `template` when `users` select my build in queryset then the queryset will save in the `models` with the `user` who select it. Every `user` can select the different different data from `templates` and the data will store in a new row in my `models` with adding `user`.

Using `form` we can save queryset in our `models` by `user`. Like this I need to save queryset in my `models` by `user`. But here I can't use `form`. I need to save this from `templates` querset. When `user` select my data(**by clicking join button**) then it will save in my `models`.

How can I do this??

Comment: This question isn't clear at all. The template doesn't do anything here other than display what's already passed as `match`. So what is it you need to save?

Comment: I think there is a misuse of terminology here. Querysets retrieve information from the database and you shouldn't need to save them to the database themselves. Are you just trying to link `user` to `match`, like with a `ManytoManyField`?

Comment: Using `for` loop there show many queryset in templates which i create by admin site. when `user` join in one query in template then it will save in a new row in my models with that `user`. when `user` join many query then it will also save in many new rows in my models with that `user`. How can I do this? @DanielRoseman

Comment: I don't know that is it need to link `user` to `match` with `manytomanyfield` or not. I just need to save my queryset with `user` when they select my queryset from my `templates`. how can it possible without using `form`?? Just `user` select my queryset from `template` and it will save in my `models` with that `user`. A `user` can select many queryset and these will save in many rows. How can i do this? @AdamStarrh

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't displaying querysets. It is displaying details of your `Match` objects. You may link two objects together (ie. `User` and `Match`) using related fields, such as `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` in the model.

Comment: In this case you could either have a hidden form that selects the correct match when the user clicks the join button, or set the `{{ match.id }}` as a data attribute on the join button and use a bit of Javascript to help you send it back to your view with a `POST` request.

Comment: I am displaying details of my `Match` objects in `template`. Now when `user` select these by clicking join button these objects will save in a new row with that `user`. How it will save with that `user`?? Give me in details answer please sir.@AdamStarrh

Comment: Yes, need a `POST` request. Please help me in details answer. I can't do it. Please help @AdamStarrh

Comment: Check out this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434920/django-posting-a-template-value-to-a-view